# how to reboot modem to change your ip using task scheduler?

Tags: ip, task, restart, scheduler, modem

i need to call a web service but it records user ip as you send request.. so you can't call it twice since your ip is stored... i need to change my ip lets say every 5 minutes.. then 7th minute i need to call that service again..

i want to use task scheduler and batch files to do so, but i don't know how to restart my modem to let it disconnect/reconnect to my ADSL service provider.

any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Usually the ADSL provider is not going to give you a new IP every time you restart the modem, and I doubt there is a way to force it.  Usually your IP address is saved with the MAC address in the DHCP table for a given amount of time (depending on the routing settings that the ISP has setup).

If you're using a Linux box you can use IP Masquerade  http://tldp.org/HOWTO/IP-Masquerade-HOWTO/

You could also use a proxy server.